# Ansible displays item is undefined in loop

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml

I am trying to execute the following ansible script, but getting error.

The file test.sh has statement "echo $1".

```
---
- name: Executing Ansible Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: testuser
  pre_tasks:
    - include_vars: global_vars.yaml
    - name: Print some debug information 
      set_fact: 
        all_vars: |
          Content of vars
          --------------------------------
          {{ vars | to_nice_json }}

  tasks:
    - name: Iterate over an array
      command: sh test.sh -i {{ item }}
      register: sh
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sh.stdout }}"
      with_items: "{{ array }}"
```

The array contains following values
`array: ["array_item1", "array_item2","array_item3","array_item4","array_item5"]`

Error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/mnt/c/ansible-test/first.yaml': line 16, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Iterate over an array\n      ^ here\n"}
```

However, if I remove the line

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ sh.stdout }}"
```

then the ansible script passes and gives the output

```
TASK [Iterate over an array] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=array_item1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=array_item2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=array_item3)
changed: [localhost] => (item=array_item4)
changed: [localhost] => (item=array_item5)
```

How can I use debug or ensure the script is executing with correct item value.

Comment: As you saw, you should have `with_items` for your `command` task rather than for `debug`.

Comment: @seshadri_c works perfectly fine...But can you please answer to my doubt that I have asked in your Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tasks, let us separate them:

1. First the `command` task - this is the main task which runs `sh test.sh -i array_item1` and so on. So it requires the *items* of the list `array`. So we have to pass `with_items: "{{ array }}"` to this task. That is why when you remove 2 lines of the `debug` task, the `with_items` is used for `command` and it works. So your main requirement should be met with just this:

   ```yaml
   - name: Iterate over an array
     command: "sh test.sh -i {{ item }}"
     with_items: "{{ array }}"
   ```
2. The `debug` task - this is an optional task. You are using this just to verify the previous task. So this task *does not need* the `array` variable. So we can add `register` to previous task, and can use the registered variable (`sh`) to see the status of previous task.

Overall, we need something like below:

```yaml
    - name: Iterate over an array
      command: "sh test.sh -i {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ array }}"
      register: sh
    - name: Show the result of previous task
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      with_items: "{{ sh.results }}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked like a charm.
Can you please tell me what was the issue in my code: was it adding name and debug task?
Also if I remove debug statement from my code will it work?

Comment: I updated my answer with some explanation.